# PySpark divide dataframe array by float

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe `dfDistance`. A sample:

```
    DataIndex CenterIndex   distances           array
        65        0          115.63     [115.63,115.01,114.14]
        65        1          115.01     [115.63,115.01,114.14]
        65        2          114.14     [115.63,115.01,114.14]
```

I want to create a new column equal to the elementwise division of the values in `array` by the corresponding value in `distances`. I have tried the following:

```
temp = dfDistance.select("DataIndex",   "CenterIndex", "distances", (np.divide(dfDistance.array, dfDistance.distances)))
```

It gave me this error:

```
"cannot resolve '(`array` / `distances`)' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(`array` / `distances`)' (array<float> and float).
```

However, when I run this:

```
    a = [115.63,115.01,114.14]
    b= 115.63
    print(np.divide([115.63,115.01,114.14], 115.63))
```

It works and gives me this result: `[ 1.          0.99463807  0.98711407]`. Why does it not work in the PySpark case, and how should I modify my code for it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it works outside is that you're working with native Python types (`list` and `float`). On the other hand, within PySpark, you're working with *column objects*, which don't act the same way.

Anyway, the simplest way to do this, I think, would be with  UDF. I tried looking through the PySpark documentation, but couldn't find any way to act on an array directly, strangely. Example:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, DoubleType

def normalise(a, dist):
    return [element / dist for element in a]

dfDistance.withColumn('normalised', F.udf(normalise, ArrayType(DoubleType()))(df['array'], df['distances']))
```

On the other hand, if you want the normalised sum, you can use `explode`:

```
distance_sum = dfDistance.select('array', F.explode('array')).groupby('array').sum()

dfDistance.join(distance_sum, on='array', how='left').withColumn('normalised_sum', F.col('sum(col)') / F.col('distances')).drop('sum(col)')
```

Comment: you saved me again, thank you! As you can see, I am new to Python/Spark, therefore, could you please explain, why inside udf you wrote ArrayType(DoubleType())? I don't get this part.

Comment: @daibri `F.udf` takes two parameters: the function and its return type. By default, all UDFs return strings (`StringType`). However, we want an array of doubles here, so we need to specify `ArrayType(DoubleType)`.

Comment: So, if I would like to return sum as a result instead of array, then I should have F.udf(normalise, DoubleType())(df['array'], df['distances']))? and the function itself would look like: return sum( [element / dist for element in a])?

Comment: @daibri Yup, you could do that. There's probably a more efficient `explode`-based approach, though.